# jQuery hide/show with each select tags

Tags: jquery, each

I have js for select it display another element by selected option (value == class) when option value equal element class its visible

how to make js work with each select elements?

here is my code:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
    if (optionValue) {
      $(".amwselected").not("." + optionValue).hide();
      $("." + optionValue).show();
    } else {
      $(".amwselected").hide();
    }
  });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="widget-as_about_me_widget" class="widefat select-img">
  <option value="gravatar">My Gravatar</option>
  <option value="custom" selected="selected">Custom Image</option>
</select>

<div class="amw-row amwselected custom">
  <input class="widefat" type="text" value="custom" />
</div><br>

<select id="widget-as_about_me_widget-select_style">
  <option value="default">default</option>
  <option value="diamond">diamond</option>
  <option value="round">round</option>
  <option value="hexagon" selected="selected">hexagon</option>
</select>

<div class="amw-row amwselected hexagon">
  <input class="widefat" type="text" value="hexagon" />
</div>
```

Comment: sorry its element not class

Comment: it work for one select tag. I want for every select

Comment: @AndreyShandrov Use a global class

Comment: when click right option in each select, each element with this class name must be visible

Comment: it still remember and be visible when another select option change

Comment: when selected (custom and hexagon) inputs below must be visible too

Comment: So what you are actually asking for is the ability to show multiple inputs, where as your logic currently is disregarding any previous selections you made, and hiding the inputs they showed.

Comment: logic is to show the div with information what I want to display by user select option and hide it. only one is right for each select in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  //create a selector that matches on any class, not just one at a time
  var filter = '.'+ $('select').map(function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(', .');
  
  //log the filter so you can see it
  console.log(filter);
  
  //hide all the things, find the ones that should show, and show them
  $(".amwselected").hide().filter(filter).show();
}).eq(0).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="widget-as_about_me_widget" class="widefat select-img">
  <option value="gravatar">My Gravatar</option>
  <option value="custom" selected="selected">Custom Image</option>
</select>

<div class="amw-row amwselected custom">
  <input class="widefat" type="text" value="custom" />
</div>

<select id="widget-as_about_me_widget-select_style">
  <option value="default">default</option>
  <option value="diamond">diamond</option>
  <option value="round">round</option>
  <option value="hexagon" selected="selected">hexagon</option>
</select>

<div class="amw-row amwselected hexagon">
  <input class="widefat" type="text" value="hexagon" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, man! works like a charm. I`m using one class for each select

Comment: $('.as-select').change(function() {
   //create a selector that matches on any class, not just one at a time
   var filter = '.'+ $('.as-select').map(function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(', .');

   //hide all the things, find the ones that should show, and show them
   $(".amwselected").hide().filter(filter).show();
 }).eq(0).change();

Comment: That'll work too.  So long as you select all of them to bind on.